# Square Webhook Curl Put request

Tags: php, curl, webhooks, square

Square's API documentation states that to setup web hooks you simply need to do the following CURL request:

curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[\"PAYMENT_UPDATED\"]" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/LOCATION_ID/webhooks

I've translated this to the following in PHP:

```
    echo "<br>curl started<br>";

    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array(
    "[\"PAYMENT_UPDATED\"]",
    );

    // set url

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ", "Content-type: application/json\r\n"));

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://connect.squareup.com/v1/XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ/webhooks");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $output;

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);     

    echo "<br>curl ends<br>";
```

but no joy, apparently my "Authorization header format incorrect" but i have no idea of how to fix it?

Comment: Read the curl manpage to learn what the switches mean, than read php's curl-api documentation and try to find the concepts from the manpage -- if you additionaly look at curl-php-code easily found via a web-search you should have code in no-time. And if that code doesn't work, come back with a question wr/ to that code.

Comment: Thanks, i had a read and it all made sense but still no joy, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your personal access token by any chance contain a $-sign? Then put the header in single quotes to prevent interpolation. Am in transit right now, will have further look later

Comment: Could you round this question out by accepting @tristansokol s answer -- if your problem is solved now, or follow up with a comment or an edit?

Answer (score 1):

You have a code issue. When you run your code you should see the following errors in addition to your described output:

```
<br>curl started<br>
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Users/tristans/Desktop/test.php on line 13

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Users/tristans/Desktop/test.php on line 15

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Users/tristans/Desktop/test.php on line 17
{"type":"unauthorized","message":"Authorization header format incorrect"}<br>
```

If you don't see that, you should increase your logging levels. The issue is that you mix up `$ch` and `$curl`

Try this code:

```
<?php
echo "<br>curl started<br>";

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(
"[\"PAYMENT_UPDATED\"]",
);

// set url

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer sq0atp-XXXXXXXXXXX", "Content-type: application/json\r\n"));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://connect.squareup.com/v1/XXXXXXXXXX/webhooks");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

echo "<br>curl ends<br>";
?>
```